# android xml RTL string resource with HTML tag

Tags: java, android, html, string, right-to-left

I have these strings in the android strings.xml file

```
<string name="format_term_and_conditional">\u200F<![CDATA[شكرًا لاختيارك <b>%1$s</b>.<br>باستخدام هذا التطبيق، يجب أن توافق على <a href=\"%2$s\"><b>شروط الاستخدام</b></a> و<a href=\"%3$s\"><b>سياسة الخصوصية</b></a> الخاصة بنا.]]></string>
<string name="format_request_permission">\u200Fشكرًا لاختيارك %1$s. يرجى منحنا الإذن التالي:\n\nإذن بطاقة الذاكرة: سيساعدنا ذلك في حفظ قائمة الراديو المفضلة الخاصة بك.</string>
<string name="format_request_permission_13">\u200F<![CDATA[شكرًا لاختيارك <b>%1$s</b>. يُرجى منح الأذونات التالية:<br><br><b>إذن الإشعارات (NOTIFICATION PERMISSION):</b> سيسمح للتطبيق بعرض إشعارات للتحكم عند الاستماع للراديو المباشر.]]></string>
```

my problem is that these texts do not view in RTL even though the app is supporting the RTL and I have added the \u200F at the beginning of each text resource to make sure that the text will show from right to left but that didn't work too

I will be thankful if anyone gave me the right answer